# Is the square of the $k$th largest eigenvalue differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $\lambda_k : \mathbb{S}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ denote the function that sends to $A$ to its $k$th largest eigenvalue, $\lambda_k(A)$. We know that $\lambda_k$ is continuous (in fact, it is Lipschitz) but not differentiable, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573394/why-is-the-largest-eigenvalue-lipschitz-continuous-and-not-differentiable).

However, is
$$
A \mapsto \lambda_k(A)^2
$$
differentiable?

Comment: What is $\mathbb S^n$??? Usually, the $n$-dimensional sphere is denoted this way.

Comment: Symmetric real.

Comment: @amsmath: It is also mildly standard for symmetric. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/808205/27978 for example. Notations like $\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ are more common, popularised (I think) by Boyd & Vandenberghe.

Comment: @copper.hat I cannot see $\mathbb S^n$ there (but $S^n$).

Comment: It was not intended to be definitive.

Comment: @copper.hat Everywhere I looked so far, I could only see $S^n$ or $S^n_{++}$, but not $\mathbb S^n$.

Comment: I should have written "appears in the wild' rather than 'mildly standard'. I have seen it frequently on blackboards in colloquia and informal discussions. Always in the context of optimisation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't hugely distinguish between $S$ and $\mathbb{S}$, that may be where my statement is misleading to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $A(t)= \begin{bmatrix} 1+t & 0 \\ 0 & 1-t \end{bmatrix}$. Then
$\lambda_1(A(t))^2 = (1+|t|)^2$ which is not differentiable.

Comment: Very nice example!